# Dynamic way of binding class type to element

Tags: java, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I have this xml format as output from different http request.

```
<transaction>
<respmsg>...</respmsg>
<respcode>0000</respcode>
<status>success</status>
</transaction>
```

Below is my Transaction Class Representation

```
@root
class Transaction {
   @Element
   public ResponseMessage respmsg;
   @Element
   public int respcode;
   @Element
   public String status;
}
```

An abstract class representation of "respmsg" property

```
abstract class ResponseMessage {

}
```

This is fairly easy to map to a Class object. However "respmsg" is different for every request
for login request the respmsg might be

```
<respmsg>
   <firstname>John</firstname>
   <lastname>Doe</lastname>
   <mobilephone>1234</mobilephone>
   <email>johndoe@test.com</email>
</respmsg>


class LoginResponseMessage extends ResponseMessage {
    @Element
    public String firstname;

    @Element
    public String lastname;

    @Element
    public String mobilephone;

    @Element
    public String email;
}
```

and for location request it might be

```
<respmsg>
   <address1>121 121 UAE Bldg, dubai</address1>
   <address2/>
   <city>Dubai</city>
   <postalcode>121</postalcode>
   <region>dubai</region>
</respmsg>

class LocationResponseMessage extends ResponseMessage {
    @Element
    public String address1;

    @Element
    public String address2;

    @Element
    public String postalcode;

    @Element
    public String region;
}
```

How do I design my class so that it knows what type of class to use for the respmsg during desserialization?

```
String xmlData = retrieve(urls[0]); //retrieve fetches the string xml from the http request
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Reader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
Transaction t = serializer.read(Transaction.class, reader, false);
```

Comment: What about adding an attribute to the `<respmsg>` tag stating which type it is?

Comment: e.g: `<respmsg type="LocationResponseMessage">`

Comment: Hi Der Flatulaor thanks for the comment. Yes, I indeed up inserting an attribute to the <respmsg> from the String xmlData.

String xmlData = retrieve(urls[0]);
int respmsgIndex = xmlData.indexOf("<respmsg>");
xmlData = xmlData.replaceFirst("<respmsg>", "<respmsg class=\"com.sample.package.LocationResponseMessage\">");

Thank you for your help. I would have mark your comment as an answer if I could. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, posting my comment as an answer:

---

What about adding an attribute to the `<respmsg>` tag stating which type it is?

For example:

```
<respmsg type="LocationResponseMessage">
```